# data.table anti-pattern when adding/modifying a new column

Tags: r, data.table, anti-patterns

I am rather new to R and working on an existing code base heavily using data.table. I understand one of the correct way to add a column or modify an existing one is:

```
my.table[ , new_column := "New Value"]
```

However I see in the existing code several calls like:

```
my.table <- my.table[ , new_column := "New Value"]
```

I understand that both calls lead to the same result. Is there any good reason I overlooked to prefer the second example?

Comment: No, stick with 1st example. I think, 2nd one is duplicating the memory.

Comment: As @zx8754 said: stick with the 1st example. See for more explanation the help-file `?":="` or the [*Reference semantics vignette*](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).

Comment: @zx8754 It isn't. Check out: `library(data.table);
DT <- iris; 
setDT(DT); 
DT1 <- DT[, x := 1]; 
DT1[, y := 2]; 
"y" %in% colnames(DT)`

Comment: @Roland correct, I wasn't sure, so I said "I think", thank you for clarifying: **2nd statement does not duplicate the memory.** The main point of my comment was to advise to use 1st example without `<-`.